# what does this piece of fortran mean?

Tags: fortran95

im trying to go through a little algorithm in fortran (im not a fortran programmer unfortunately) but i need to understand what its doing:
here it is,

```
  omega = 0.d0
  s = 1.d0
  i = 1
  j = 2
  k = 3
101 do iperm = 1, 3
     omega = omega + s * a1 (i) * a2 (j) * a3 (k)
     l = i
     i = j
     j = k
     k = l
  enddo
  i = 2
  j = 1
  k = 3
  s = - s

  if (s.lt.0.d0) goto 101

  omega = abs (omega) * alat**3
```

`a1,a2,a3` are vectors (three elements each, real values, representing vectors in 3d space)
`s` is a unit integer (can be 1 or -1 alternately) and `i,j,k` are integers while `omega` (which is what i need to understand how its arrived at) is a floating point value, so is `alat`.
Now what is going on  up there? 
especially  the `iperm =1,3`  part, is that a vector being created? at first i thought iperm might be some  fancy function/routine or iterator, but after some search i think thats not the case,  whats the purpose of the iperm? 
is there some looping over `iperm`  between "`do`" and "`enddo`" ?

Comment: When I googled "fortran do" the first several links explained what the `do`/`enddo` construct does. You should first attempt a google search for such basic questions about the language, then post questions here if you still don't understand.

Comment: If `s` is "a unit integer," why is it (a) given a double-precision value `1.d0` and (b) compared to a double-precision value `0.d0`?

Comment: it should simply be a unit value (can be positive or negative), not sure why the writer chose to use a floating point to represent it, but i would imagine its neccessary for it to have a sign, so that seems like as good a choice as any.

Comment: See my comment on Mark's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you've got is a sequence of assignments with a loop thrown in for fun.  I guess you understand that statement such as

```
lhs = rhs
```

evaluates `rhs` and assigns the result to the variable `lhs`.

The line

```
101 do iperm = 1, 3
```

starts a `do` loop.  The `101` is a statement label, it's used later.  The loop comprises all the statements from that line to the line `enddo`.  The loop will be executed 3 times (once for each of the integers in the sequence starting at `1` and ending at `3`).  The loop control variable `iperm` is assigned these values in turn.  The loop is a little unusual in that the loop variable is not used inside the loop.  The statement

```
omega = omega + s * a1 (i) * a2 (j) * a3 (k)
```

updates the value of `omega`.  The term `a1(i)` (the space in your original is immaterial) means `the i-th element of array a1`.  *et cetera*

When the line

```
if (s.lt.0.d0) goto 101
```

is executed if `s` is less than `0` control goes bak to the line labelled `101`.

Finally, the term `alat**3` calculates the cube of `alat`.

So now get a piece of paper and figure out what value `omega` gets.

Comment: Without paper, nor executing the code, it looks like an astute way of computing the [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of three vectors. And last line assigns to omega the volume of a parallelepiped, where *alat* is probably a scale factor. Nice piece of code, although not the most efficient (there are 12 multiplications, but [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) would do it with only 9).

Comment: By the way, it comes from [Quantum ESPRESSO](http://www.quantum-espresso.org/), available [here](http://qe-forge.org/gf/project/q-e/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=18). See in the end of latgen.f90 [here](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/espresso_v5.0.1/i386_ubuntu1204/espresso-5.0.1/flib/latgen.f90) or [there](http://qmctools.googlecode.com/svn/dft/espresso-4.2/flib/latgen.f90). Except there is no scaling factor in the last assignment to omega.

Comment: @arbautjc yes its from QE, i eventually figured out its used to calculate the volume of a primitive unit cell, (i was looking specifically at flib/volume.f90). thanks!